# python reflection to find referencing object

Tags: python, reflection

If I have the following code

```
 class One:
   scope = 'first_scope'

 class Two:
   scope = 'second_scope'
   contained_object = One()
```

Is it possible for me given a reference to  `contained_object` to determine through reflection whether it and the object referencing it have the same `scope`?

Thanks

EDIT: Apologies if the question was unclear, I wasn't quite sure in python terminology how to ask it. I've contrived a sort of sample

An example might be

```
 def sample(input):
     #code in here to find out if input.scope
     # matches a.scope without having a reference to it

 a = Two()
 a.scope = 'first scope'
 a.contained_object.scope = 'will not match'
 sample(a.contained_object)
```

Comment: Your question is a little obscure to me, could you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Rik Poggi Thanks for letting me know, I've added a sample to try and explain what I meant.

Comment: Your example looks strange, why can't you pass `a` to the `sample` function and let it call `a.contained_object`? What's the background of your question? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's an inversion of control situation. My code is passed a.contained_object and to reduce the size of a query I want to check for objects only in the same scope as the referencing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable, you can do something like:

```
import gc

    class A(object):
        scope = 'a'

    class B(object):
        scope = 'b'
        contained = A()

    b = B()

    print gc.get_referrers(b.contained)[0]['scope']
```

However, there are two more problems:
1. Why do you want to do it at the first place? I have a very bad feeling about this, unless you have a very good reason, otherwise, i will never suggest you to do it.
2. You need to figure out how to pick the right object when it has multiple referrers - `get_referrers()` return a list of dicts representing all the objects referring the given one.

You need to describe your question more specifically to get a better answer.

Comment: that is what I was looking for. The question relates to an inversion of control situation where I am passed the 'contained' object and would like to search a database only for objects in the same scope to minimise time.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unclear. If you mean that you are in a context in which the variables `contained_object` and `scope` exist, and `contained_object` holds an object which has the property `scope`, then yes, of course you can.

If you mean that you simply have an object of type `One`, and you want to find the references to it, you can use `gc.get_referrers` ( http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers )

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was referring to when you have an object of type One and wanted to find references to it.